# jQuery function is not firing on Backbone View Render

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone ItemView that has some DIVs with its classes and one DIV has the class `active`.

I write a jQuery line to hide all elements there hasn't the class `active` but it's not working.

```
    Show.EventItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: '#id-template',
        events: {
            'click #js-tabs li.js-tab': 'tabs'
        },
        tabs: function(e) {
            var target = e.target,
                tab_id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('js-data-tab-id');

            $('#js-tabs .js-tab-content').hide();
            $('#js-tabs .js-tab-content#' + tab_id).show();
        },
        initialize: function() {
            $('#js-tabs .js-tab-content:not(.active)').hide();
            console.log('Initialized');
        }
    });
```

The "Initialized" text is being displayed on console but the elements that hasn't the class `active` are not being hidded.

If run this line `$('#js-tabs .js-tab-content:not(.active)').hide();` directly in Chrome Console, is working but should fire automatically on view render (or other method).

Thank you for any advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initialize()` is called when the view is instantiated and before the `render()` method. That means that the view hasn't been rendered yet. `Marionette.ItemView` gives you some helpful callback methods to use.

`onRender()` is called on each render. If you synchronise models to server this may be called several times, when the model content updates.

`onShow()` is called once per view shown in a region. If you use [regions](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.region.html) then use this.

Comment: Thank you @vassiiskrikonis. Using the `onShow()` method works fine. [Here is](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/viewlifecycle.html#show-view-events) some extra infos about these methods.

Answer (score 0):

In Backbone view, initialize is the first method that is executed when a view is being rendered. so here you are trying to manipulate even before the view is rendered.

Try to move that code into the render function or after the view(page/content) is loaded.

Also try to debug in console with breakpoints to make sure if the content is loaded before executing that line of code.